# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in Three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d

I am trying to create a wave effect on an image using Three.js, I am following this tutorial on youtube to do so : -

[Tutorial That I Followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su1n2Uuf38E&t=1095s)

After completing the code, I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error in my console and the wireframe is also not visible.
Maybe this is due to the new Three.js update that introduced BufferGeometry instead of normal one.

My Js Code is as follows :-

```js
const section = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true, 
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
section.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'Wrapper2 Central.jpg' );

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(7.5, 4 , 50, 30);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    
    map: texture 
});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

cube.rotation.set(0, 0, 0)

camera.position.z = 5;

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

function animate() {
    const t = clock.getElapsedTime()

    cube.geometry.vertices.map( v => {
        const wavex1 = 0.5 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 * t)
        const wavex2 = 0.25 * Math.sin(v.x * 3 * t * 2)
        const wavex3 = 0.5 * Math.sin(v.y * t)

        v.z = wavex1 + wavex2 + wavex3
    })

    cube.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate()

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `geometry.vertices` anymore, as `THREE.Geometry()` was deprecated since r125, and how all geometry constructors return `THREE.BufferGeometry`, where vertices are stored in `geometry.attributes.position`:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.125.2/build/three.module.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true, 
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg' );

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(7.5, 4 , 50, 30);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    
    map: texture 
});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

cube.rotation.set(0, 0, 0)

camera.position.z = 5;

const clock = new THREE.Clock()
let v = new THREE.Vector3();
let pos = cube.geometry.attributes.position;

function animate() {
    const t = clock.getElapsedTime()
    
    for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
      v.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
      const wavex1 = 0.5 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 * t)
      const wavex2 = 0.25 * Math.sin(v.x * 3 * t * 2)
      const wavex3 = 0.5 * Math.sin(v.y * t)

      pos.setZ(i, wavex1 + wavex2 + wavex3)
      
    }
    pos.needsUpdate = true;

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you much guys. it's working now.. the wave is animating from both of the sides but I need to make it wave from one side of the plane. i.e :- just like a flag wave.. will work on it. Thanks Guys.